# DXTabControl loads multiple Webbrowser Tabs slow

Tags: performance, time, tabs, devexpress

I'm using a DXTabControl from DevExpress to show multiple WebBrowser Tabs in an Application. 
For every Tab of this Webpage is opened, the loading time is longer.

The First Tab is very fast, the second Tab slower, and the third Tab is unusable slow.

I only open a Webbrowser in this DXControlTab.

What could be a possible Problem?

```cs
private void LoadPage() {
  UriBuilder uriSite = new UriBuilder(P_HTTPPage) 
  try {
    P_WebBrowser.Navigate(uriSite.Uri);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any code you can share? Without some details you probably will not get the help you need.

Comment: You can [edit] your question, don't post code in comments